# Move ImageView with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-studio, imageview, position

I'm trying to move an ImageView with this code:

```
img.animate().translationY(110).setDuration(1500);
```

But if I try to move it again later with something like:

```
img.animate().translationY(-110).setDuration(1500);
```

The ImageView moves from where it used to be before I moved it in the first place.
What I would expect is for it to return to it's original position. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
img.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(1500);
```

Comment: that would work if I ALWAYS wanted the ImageView to return to its original position, but thats not the case. I'm actually moving it around inside a grid so it can go down, left, right or up

Comment: you said in your post that you want Image to retrun to its original position. Now tell me what exactly you need??

Comment: I said that if I move it down and then up again, I would expect it to return to its original position. Instead of moving all the way up from what it original position was. I want it to keep moving from the place it already is.

Comment: so it will follow a regular pattern of animation or at any time it can move up,down,left or right??

Comment: It can move on any direction, either randomly or by user input.

Answer (score 0):

you should use animationSet and also -

```
animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just get the translation and add it?

```
public void ClickMoveDown{
float distance = 100;
Move (0,distance)
}

private void Move (float x, float y){
img.animate().translationX(img.getTranslationX+x).setDuration(1500);
img.animate().translationY(img.getTranslationY+y).setDuration(1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to move it after (in your case) 1.5 seconds is passed

```
float originalPosition = img.getY();
img.animate().translationY(110).setDuration(1500).start();
img.animate().translationY(originalPosition).setStartDelay(1500).setDuration(1500).start();
```

im not so sure about the method names..

Answer (score 0):

```
TranslateAnimation animationDown = new TranslateAnimation(00.0f, 00.0f, 00.0f, 500);
animationDown.setDuration(800);
animationDown.setRepeatMode(android.view.animation.Animation.REVERSE);
animationDown.setRepeatCount(android.view.animation.Animation.INFINITE);
```

This will make the image move straight down then reverse its track back up to its original spot maintaining speed. Also take note you can make multiple of these and add them to one animation set to get the desired square pattern i believe how you would store it into a set is as such...

```
 AnimationSet example = new AnimationSet(true);

example.addAnimation(animationDown);
```

"" and so on until

```
s.setStartTime();
```

or

```
 s.startAnimationSet();
```